# Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) using JSONP and Web Workers

Tags: cross-domain, jsonp, web-worker

I am looking for solution how to get/send the data from/to another domain using JSONP in the Web Workers.

Since the Web Workers have not access to the DOM it is not possible to append the `<script>` tag with the url and callback parameter to the `<head>` tag from Web Workers.

Does anybody know, how to get/post the data from/to another domain using JSONP and Web Workers?

Thanks,

Comment: Status update please? If my answer solved the problem, I'd appreciate a "Best Answer" checkmark. If not, please tell me why so I can improve it.

Answer (score 4):

CORS is a specification which has nothing to do with JSONP beyond making it obsolete in newer browsers. It enables cross-domain requests using ordinary XMLHttpRequest calls.

Here's [an overview](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) of how it works and how to use it. It can be used in Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, Chrome 3+, Internet Explorer 8+, and [anything else using one of the same engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this code:

```
// Helper function to make the server requests 
function MakeServerRequest() 
{
    importScripts("http://SomeServer.com?jsonp=HandleRequest");
} 

// Callback function for the JSONP result 
function HandleRequest(objJSON) 
{
    // Up to you what you do with the data received. In this case I pass 
    // it back to the UI layer so that an alert can be displayed to prove 
    // to me that the JSONP request worked. 
    postMessage("Data returned from the server...FirstName: " 
                  + objJSON.FirstName + " LastName: " + objJSON.LastName);
} 

// Trigger the server request for the JSONP data 
MakeServerRequest();
```

Comment: That is excellent! I was really starting to think a cross domain ajax call from a WebWorker was impossible. Thanks!