# How call soap service using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, soap

I have a problem with calling soap service from php page. I was implemented two page,first page was created in php, and second page was created in asp.net. In asp.net application I have SOAP service, which methods should be called from php.

Method on my SOAP service,  look like this:

```
[WebMethod]

[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public bool UpdateVotes(string vote) {
           //Code 
 }
```

On PHP application I call UpdateVotes method on the next way:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:5690/VoteServices.asmx/UpdateVotes",
                data: "{'vote': '" + vote + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {                   
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {                  
                }
            });
```

First I run asp.net application with SOAP service, and than I start php aplication.

When i click on button for calling web method on service i browser console i got this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:5690/VoteServices.asmx/UpdateVotes
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5690/VoteServices.asmx/UpdateVotes. Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: did you google the error message?

Comment: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin  - you should read a bit for JSONP, CORS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616440/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-using-jsonp-and-web-workers

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1.) This isn't a [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) service any longer since you are passing [JSON](http://www.json.org/) back and forth.

2.) You are running into a security restriction called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is designed to prevent malicious scripts from calling evil web services and sending them all your data from the browser. Basically, you can't make any Cross Domain requests (i.e. a different domain than where the script originated) that aren't using the GET [HTTP verb](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).