# AJAX HEAD request for offsite file/directory

Tags: ajax

I have an AJAX call that check to see if a file exists.  Success displays the file, failure doesn't.  Troubleshooting the `type: HEAD,` property of AJAX.  It prefixes the called URL with the domain of the scripts origination.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var agentuid = $('#agentuid').val();
    var imgurl = 'http://www.universaldynamicmedia.com/sandbox/singleprop_img/agencies/' + agentuid  + '.png';
    var img = '<img id="firm_pic"  src="' + imgurl + '" />';

    $.ajax({
        url: imgurl,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function() {
            $('#firmlogo').append('<h1>FAIL!</h1>');
        },
        success: function() {
            $('#firmlogo').html('<h1>SUCCESS!</h1>');
        }
    });
});
```

When it tries to find the url as defined in `var imgurl`, it kicks back an error with this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://theimgurl.com/image1.png Origin http://www.therequesturl.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there a way to cross domain a HEAD request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) using JSONP and Web Workers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616440/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-using-jsonp-and-web-workers)

Comment: That question deals with JSONP and Web Workers.

Comment: Yeah, I was too quick on the button and wanted to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your request is successful there is no content to restrict you from (because of the head request), but when you get an error an error document is sent (I've only checked this in Apache) so then there is content to block due to SOP. [http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/DGa7V/5/](http://goo.gl/EImOSX)