# How to get web workers to function cross domain, multiple browsers? IE SCRIPT5022: SecurityError

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cross-domain, cors, web-worker

I have created web workers that are being called from both a separate file and inline workers (blobs).  Neither of which will work consistently in most browsers.  I am using CORs following the the tutorials below.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

The issues is that when I use inline workers (blobs) they work in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE, Safari, or Opera.  This code will be used for tracking purpose, so will need to work across many domains.

On the backend I have:

`Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

on the front end I have

```
            var blob = new Blob([
                "POST to a page that colllects information about what has been clicked usng CORs"]);

            // Obtain a blob URL reference
            var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            var workerBlob = new Worker(blobURL);

            workerBlob.onmessage = function (event) {
                withWorker.removeEventListener('click', addBtnClickListener, false);
                withWorker.click();
                return true;
                //the worker is tracking a button click
            };
            workerBlob.postMessage(url);

            //release the blob
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
```

Is there another way to get web workers inline (blobs) or other wise to work cross domain?

Comment: there are additional CORS headers, for example `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`. Maybe your server does not allow a specific HTTP verb?

Comment: I don't think that's the issues I am using Thinktecture.IdentityModel  and with CorsConfig.AllowAll();  if it's configured correctly.  First time using it

Comment: WebWorkers do not support CORS yet. However, you can use ajax blob download and use the blob url to instantiate the worker. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-html5/QoiTEAkYJCI

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) using JSONP and Web Workers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616440/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-using-jsonp-and-web-workers)